# Switching styles with jQuery, but don't change all of them

Tags: jquery, css, styles, switch-statement

Situation: I have two style sheets, one has color info (switches depending on subfolder), the other has everything else.

I need to swap the main css for sizing buttons.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="cookie.js"></script>
<script>
  if($.cookie("css")) {
     $("link").attr("href",$.cookie("css"));
  }
  $(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#nav li a").click(function() { 
     $("link").attr("href",$(this).attr('rel'));
     $.cookie("css",$(this).attr('rel'), {expires: 365, path: '/'});
     return false;
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
            <ul id="nav" style="float:right">
            <li><a href="#" rel="style1024.css">one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="style.css">two</a></li>
            </ul>
```

It works great, the only problem is that the switcher seems to also switch the color styles to the clicked ones.
Can this be solved with an id tag?

I have this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='main-css'  href='style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='color-css'  href='teal.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

But how do I make the JS change only the "main-css rel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select on ID, just like in CSS:

```
$("#main-css").attr("href",$.cookie("css"));
```

Comment: Guess its late. Thanks for the tip, really appreciate it!